# project dependencies order - VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dependencies, dependency-properties

should my project dependency order be:

a.lib depends on ab.lib, a.lib depends on ac.lib

or

ab.lib depends on a.lib, ac.lib depends on a.lib

**from a.lib** contains base classes/functions used by other libs

***FILE a.h***

```
class A
{
public:
 virtual void Update();

 // base function declarations here
 // ...
}
```

**from ab.lib** overrides, implements and extends class A

***FILE b.h***

```
#include "a.h"
class B : public A
{
public:
 // overridden functions here
 // ...
 void Update();
}
```

**from ac.lib** overrides, implements and extends class A

***FILE c.h***

```
#include "a.h"
class C : public A
{
public:
 // overridden functions here
 // ...
 void Update();
}
```

Having tested a similar albeit more complex scenario than this simplified version Visual Studio 2013 doesn't seem to care which way round I set my dependencies up. This has me worried.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's just say class A's declaration is in a.h
>
> How do you compile ab.cpp (contains class B's definition), by #include'ing "a.h"?
>    How do you compile ac.cpp (contains class C's definition), by #include'ing "a.h"?

Right?

It means Compile time dependencies have already been set, hence VS 2013 doesn't complain.

> ab.lib depends on a.lib, ac.lib depends on a.lib

- This project dependency is order is correct since when you try to build ab.lib, VS 2013 will first check if a.lib is up-to-date, if a.lib is found up-to-date and then VS proceed to build ab.lib. If not a.lib is built first. This is obvious since ab.lib (class B) is dependent on a.lib (class A). Same thing with ac.lib.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: your assumptions are correct, I'll edit my question to make that obvious. thanks for explaining why VS2013 doesn't complain. So that being said which way round should the dependencies correctly be set. Thanks.

Comment: ab.lib depends on a.lib, ac.lib depends on a.lib

Comment: could you elaborate on why that is the case. (also post as an answer as opposed to a comment and I will mark your elaborated answer as such). Thanks in advance.